# how to get the distance in meters?

Tags: node.js, geolocation

I want to get the distance between two latlongs. I have a array of lat longs , and I've written the code like this:

I import library the library

```
npm i geo-distance
```

then

```
for (let i = 0; i < data[0].coordinates.length - 1; i++) {
        const latlong1 = {
          'lat': parseFloat(data[0].coordinates[i].latitude),
          'lon': parseFloat(data[0].coordinates[i].longitude),
        };
        const latlong2 = {
          'lat': parseFloat(data[0].coordinates[i + 1].latitude),
          'lon': parseFloat(data[0].coordinates[i + 1].longitude),
        };

        this.distance = Distance.between(latlong1, latlong2);
        logger.info('Distance ' + this.distance);
      }
```

but i got the response like "0.00000185803153523537". how to get the response in meters .....can you please tell me if any alternative methods there

Comment: https://github.com/walling/geo-distance/issues/5. see this issue no way you can do that using this NPM

Comment: but i want the response in meters...in that above link there is no option for meters...and i want to calculate the distance in road map view, not in straight line view

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/distance - worth trying this one.

Comment: @raj If the NPM doesn't support you can't get it anyway. Try for other npm which suits your requirement

Comment: ok ... can you please suggest me any npm library for getting distance for road view latlong not for straight line

Comment: try for what @ Ashish Modi suggested.In that thread also they are suggesting the same

Comment: i tried that one but how to declare import in ts file...?

Comment: @AshishModi how import the dependence in typescript after npm i @turf/distance

Comment: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/1568 - this should help you

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using this specific library, then you can use its built in method `human_readable` to get the distance in either meters or km, depending on the distance. You will then need to parse that human readable distance, in order to get a consistent numeric value in meters. I suggest the following:

```js
const distHumanReadable = Distance.between(latlong1, latlong2).human_readable();
const numericValue = +(distHumanReadable.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
this.distance = distHumanReadable.endsWith('km') ? numericValue * 1000 : numericValue;
```